# Passing a dynamic URL to a DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We are using salesforce connect and have a payment URL that is specific to a customer.  How do I pass that URL to a DocuSign envelope so that the customer, while signing the envelope, can click a link to be directed to their unique payment page.  We have used #HREF for similar functionality, but this creates a static destination (via the data tag and tool tip) and we need it to be dynamic and something we can generate creating the envelope.  Can we modify the tool tip text on a custom tag when the envelope is created, or is there another way to meet this requirement?

Comment: Not sure if you can do this, DocuSign does not allow active hyperlinks inside the documents for security purposes I believe.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this from Salesforce, through the web console or the API it is possible with #HREF tags. But Salesforce doesn't have a way to dynamically fill this out on send. You could have it in your template and your users fill it out with the "Tag" button as a workaround.